# How can I gather int in System.out.print

Tags: java, int

```
public class Variables {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
int a = 5;
int b = 11;
```

So i have to make a = 11 and b = 5. I thought I can do it when i gather 5 and 6 and draw 6 of 11. 
I thought : System.out.println(a + 6);
            System.out.println(b - 6);
will work but unfortunately it has to say : "Gives 11
                                             Gives 5"
so my tactic didn't work.
I would be thankful if you help me

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. What do you want to do ? What is the expected output ? Your question is very unclear....

Comment: my task is : You have two variables:
int a = 5;
int b = 11;
Write a program with which to swap their values, ie System.out.print (a) gives 11, and System.out.print (b) gives 5.

Comment: Ooo I see ! (wow, how could I figure that out from your question ?!?!!) . Well, to answer, the easiest way is to have a third variable (say x), then copy a to x, then b to a, then x to b and you are done....

Comment: thank you very much and i am new in this site. I started programming with java not long ago and i still don't understand some things :) Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need to do is just switch the values of `a` and `b`(which is how I understood your explanation) and you're allowed to switch the values through new variables, just create a temporary variable to switch them.

```
public class Variables {

public static void main(String[] args) {

      int a = 5;
      int b = 11;

      int temp = b;
      b = a;

      System.out.println("A gives " + temp + " B gives " + b);
}
```

Comment: @VenetsiaKrusteva not a problem. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, to print to the console, you write

```
System.out.println(/*some String here*/);
```

You can either create String s and then pass it to System.out.println(s), or you can anonymously construct the string:

```
System.out.println("foo");
```

If you want to concatenate strings, you use the "+" symbol:

```
System.out.println("foo " + a + " bar");
```

Don't forget the spaces in there.  Hope this helps and good luck.

Comment: thank you for your time :) it helped me a bit, I understood when we use "+" but i can't write 5+6 in system.out.put

Comment: No problem! Glad you're question was answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without temporary variable:

```
a = (a + b) - (b = a);
```

Comment: Thank u for your time. I see there are a lot of solutions. Thanks